# How to use 2 dependencies with the same folder structure?

Tags: asynchronous, logging, log4j2

ISSUE : We have a legacy logging framework code base that is used by multiple apps as a dependency. It uses googlecode Disruptor library. The later projects which are build in Springboot need to use Disruptor from lmax org. There is a clash in the folder structure as they are exactly same. However, the implementations are slightly different. We need to use both as the older code can break if we use the lmax based Disruptor.

We need to use the lmax dependecy for the async logging.

Any suggestions on how to use 2 librabries with the same classes will be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

The already used dependency : com.googlecode.disruptor:disruptor:2.8
New dependency to be used(along with the older) com.lmax.disruptor:3.3.6

Both the libraries have exactly same folder structure for Disruptor class.